# Screening interview with agency before company

Tags: united-kingdom, contractors

I've been contacted by a recruiter about an IT contract role, which sounded interesting but then they called me again and said they're obviously keen to put me forward but that I'd have to do an 30m interview with them first. I wasn't keen on that, and the 30m went to 15-20 - but I'm just wondering what's the real point of this, and how commonplace it is ? I find it hard to believe that a company looking to hire senior developers will not do their own screening.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere fair point, but it is quite unusual in my experience, and at least one other London-based deceloper i asked aobut this. Generally recruiters seem happy with the CV and a short, informal conversation - which would be mostly about the role.

Answer (score 14):

It is quite common. An external recruiter will want to know you first before forwarding your application to the company, for a bunch of reasons:

- they want to see what kind of person you are. They will be forwarding your application to the company, so in a way *you* will reflect on *them*. They want to make sure the action is positive;
- they want to see if you are available or if there are any strings attached with your particular application (maybe you have some conditions, for ex);
- they want to see if your profile actually matches with the role the company is looking for, if not very obvious from your CV;
- sometimes they ask for a pay range you are available to work for and see if that matches the budget the company is willing to pay;
- they want to tell you more about the job and see if you are interested;
- sometimes they use this chance to do a "prep call" and give you some pointers (if you get the job they get a commission so it's also in their interest for you to get the job);
- it's sometimes a pre-screening required by the company (so they get only specific candidates);
- any number of other factors specific to their internal practices or the company job description or preference;

Seems this is the first time this happened to you, but it's a common practice. As mentioned in the comments, if that bothers you just say "no thanks" and move on.

But even if it's a 15 min talk, you might find out you don't like the position, or the company, or the project, or technology, etc, in which case this can save you a one or two hours of the real technical interview you will have to attend as a senior developer if they send your CV to the company directly.

Answer (score 6):

In the USA this is very common. The recruiting agency wants to vet you first, to get to know you, to make sure you're a suitable candidate for the position, to make sure there isn't anything that would risk their standing with the client if they put you forward with the client, to make sure you understand the position and have a genuine interest in landing it, etc., etc.